# How do I retrieve the path to my dylib at runtime?

Tags: c++, c, macos, dylib

On OS X, how can code in a dylib find the path it was loaded from, at runtime?

Coming from a Windows background, I'm used being able to call `GetModuleFileName(dllHandle,...)`.

There exists `NSGetExecutablePath()` which will give me the path of the executable for the current process. Is there an equivalent to give me the current dylib path?

Comment: +1 for mentioning NSGetExecutablePath, the solution to the problem that brought me to this page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [dladdr(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dladdr.3.html). Given a memory address, dladdr() outputs a structure that has, amongst other data, the path of the library containing the address. For example, inside your library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void test(void) {
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(test, &info)) {
        printf("Loaded from path = %s\n", info.dli_fname);
    }
}
```